# Pandas - Working on multiple columns seems slow

Tags: python, performance, csv, pandas, lambda

I have some trouble processing a big csv with Pandas. Csv consists of an index and about other 450 columns in groups of 3, something like this:

```
    cola1    colb1   colc1   cola2    colb2   colc2   cola3    colb3   colc3
1  stra_1  ctrlb_1  retc_1  stra_1  ctrlb_1  retc_1  stra_1  ctrlb_1  retc_1
2  stra_2  ctrlb_2  retc_2  stra_2  ctrlb_2  retc_2  stra_2  ctrlb_2  retc_2
3  stra_3  ctrlb_3  retc_3  stra_3  ctrlb_3  retc_3  stra_3  ctrlb_3  retc_3
```

For each trio of columns I would like to "analyze B column (it's a sort of "CONTROL field" and depending on its value I should then return a value by processing col A and C.

Finally I need to return a concatenation of all resulting columns starting from 150 to 1.

I already tried with apply but it seems too slow (10 min to process 50k rows).

```
df['Path'] = df.apply(lambda x: getFullPath(x), axis=1)
```

with an example function you can find here:
https://pastebin.com/S9QWTGGV

I tried extracting a list of unique combinations of cola,colb,colc - preprocessing the list - and applying map to generate results and it speeds up a little:

```
for i in range(1,151):
  df['Concat' + str(i)] = df['cola' + str(i)] + '|' + df['colb' + str(i)] + '|' + df['colc' + str(i)]

concats = []
for i in range(1,151):
  concats.append('Concat' + str(i))

ret = df[concats].values.ravel()
uniq = list(set(ret))
list = {}

for member in ret:
  list[member] = getPath2(member)

for i in range(1,MAX_COLS + 1):
  df['Res' + str(i)] = df['Concat' + str(i)].map(list)

df['Path'] = df.apply(getFullPath2,axis=1)
```

function getPath and getFullPath2 are defined as example here:
https://pastebin.com/zpFF2wXD

But it seems still a little bit slow (6 min for processing everything)
Do you have any suggestion on how I could speed up csv processing?
I don't even know if the way I using to "concatenate" columns could be better :), tried with Series.cat but I didn't get how to chain only some columns and not the full df

Thanks very much!
Mic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amended answer: I see from your criteria, you actually have multiple controls on each column. I think what works is to split these into 3 dataframes, applying your mapping as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

series = {
  'cola1': pd.Series(['D_1','C_1','E_1'],index=[1,2,3]),
  'colb1': pd.Series(['ret1','ret1','ret2'],index=[1,2,3]),
  'colc1': pd.Series(['B_1','C_2','B_3'],index=[1,2,3]),
  'cola2': pd.Series(['D_1','C_1','E_1'],index=[1,2,3]),
  'colb2': pd.Series(['ret3','ret1','ret2'],index=[1,2,3]),
  'colc2': pd.Series(['B_2','A_1','A_3'],index=[1,2,3]),
  'cola3': pd.Series(['D_1','C_1','E_1'],index=[1,2,3]),
  'colb3': pd.Series(['ret2','ret2','ret1'],index=[1,2,3]),
  'colc3': pd.Series(['A_1','B_2','C_3'],index=[1,2,3]),
}

your_df = pd.DataFrame(series, index=[1,2,3], columns=['cola1','colb1','colc1','cola2','colb2','colc2','cola3','colb3','colc3'])

# Split your dataframe into three frames for each column type
bframes = your_df[[col for col in your_df.columns if 'colb' in col]]
aframes = your_df[[col for col in your_df.columns if 'cola' in col]]
cframes = your_df[[col for col in your_df.columns if 'colc' in col]]
for df in [bframes, aframes, cframes]:
    df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3']

# Mapping criteria
def map_colb(c):
    if c == 'ret1':
        return 'A'
    elif c == 'ret2':
        return None
    else:
        return 'F'

def map_cola(a):
      if a.startswith('D_'):
        return 'D'
      else:
        return 'E'

def map_colc(c):
    if c.startswith('B_'):
        return 'B'
    elif c.startswith('C_'):
        return 'C'
    elif c.startswith('A_'):
        return None
    else:
        return 'F'
# Use it on each frame
aframes = aframes.applymap(map_cola)
bframes = bframes.applymap(map_colb)
cframes = cframes.applymap(map_colc)

# The trick here is filling 'None's from the left to right in order of precedence
final = bframes.fillna(cframes.fillna(aframes))
# Then just combine them using whatever delimiter you like
# df.values.tolist() turns a row into a list
pathlist = ['|'.join(item) for item in final.values.tolist()]
```

This gives a result of:

```
In[70]: pathlist
Out[71]: ['A|F|D', 'A|A|B', 'B|E|A']
```

Comment: Thanks very much, i'll be trying your approach very soon..
you can find a small example of criteria/dataset in the pasebin links in the first post
I'll keep you updated!

Comment: As per what i understood applymap works only on Series.<br/>
In my case the hard part is to get a value resulting from values of every trio of columns:
`if (colb1 == 1):
  return cola
else:
  return colb
`
That's why I tried apply

Comment: Applymap also works on dataframes elementwise see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html

What error are you getting if the above isn't working?

Comment: Wow just tried it and it seems to be something like 500% faster than my (worse) solution!

Comment: Great, glad I could help :)